# Identifying major and minor road instersections

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, intersect

I’m trying to identify and capture the intersection of a major roads (in red) and the minor roads (in black). The blue circles in my snapshot are the spots I’m trying to identify.
The problem with the data I have, the two datasets sometime do not intersect.
I tried to add ‘Tolerance’ while I use the Intersect tool in ArcMap, but since the lines do not intersect, it did not catch those point.
What tool or tools do I need to use? TIA

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make points from endpoints. Assign an ID from the road to the point. Buffer the point. Assign ID from point to buffer.

For each minor road endpoint buffer (using modelbuilder), select by location (intersect) major roads intersecting that buffer, and calculate a field based on the field ID of the intersecting road. Then each of your buffers will have an ID for both the minor road and the almost-intersecting major road.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way with the help of @Mox:

1. adding end-point to the minor roads (both ends).
2. run a Locate Features Along Route with he desired Search Radius.
3. And then run Display Route Events which place the points on the main route.

This method can only be done if your major road is LRS.